# Chrome inspect devices broken default window shape

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, android-debug

I am facing an issue while using `chrome://inspect#devices` to debug my android app.
DevTools window is broken I look like this (but it was ok recently).

I have done the following:

- re-install chrome from scratch with deleting all its cache (removed
  folder `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`)
- reset chrome devtools settings (devtools -> settings -> appearance -> restore
  defaults & reload)

I noticed this glitch after I had used `chrome://tracing` to load ***.html** file that was generated by `python systrace.py` command

Environment:

- Chrome 89.0.4389.82 (x86_64)
- MacOS BigSur 11.1

Thank you!

**Update:**

Recently my teammate had sent me the same screenshot of this issue. But he's using Windows OS.

[image]

Comment: Looks like bug in Chrome which you can report on https://crbug.com. Meanwhile use an older version of Chrome (e.g. a portable).

Answer (score 1):

I'v found the explanation of this problem [here](https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/696)

For now, the solution is to use chromium browser for your platform:

- Linux x64: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/827102/
- Mac OS: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/827102/
- Windows:https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win/827102/

Comment: Please try to make your answer useful even without links :)